# using both server-side rendering and client-side rendering in a react webapp

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, client-side

so i'm working on building a webapp in react, the "public" part with landing page and all should be in server-side rendering since that's best for the search engine, but there is a whole other part that will be hidden behind authentication that can be done using client-side rendering since i dont need SEO capabilities, or at least that's what ive learned during my researching this topic. however i'm stuck on implementing it, do i need to separate folders for that? separate routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to separate them, you can use Nextjs... On pages you don't need server side, you set ssr to false and also add those pages to your disallow rule in your robots.txt